# Is there a difference between Image.GenerateEmptyAlternateText and just setting Image.AlternateText = "" in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The title says it all, really.

I've found the`Image.GenerateEmptyAlternateText` property on the ASP.NET `Image` control and now I'm wondering if there's any difference in setting 
`<asp:Image GenerateEmptyAlternateText="True" />` and `<asp:Image AlternateText="" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out setting AlternateText="" doesn't work to set an empty alt text, if it set to an empty string, it gets omitted when the image HTML is rendered. To get alt="", one has to use the GenerateEmptyAlternateText property.

See below from "[Accessibility in Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2009/07/31/accessibility-in-visual-studio-2010-and-asp-net-4.aspx)"

> ASP.NET controls that render images omit the alt attribute in the
>   rendered HTML if you simply assign an empty string to the
>   AlternateText property. For example, suppose you add the following
>   ASP.NET Image control to a page:
>
> ```
> <asp:Image ImageUrl="PageDivider.gif" AlternateText="" Runat="Server" />
> ```
>
> In this case, the following HTML is rendered:
>
> ```
> <img src="PageDivider.gif" />
> ```
>
> Notice that the alt attribute has disappeared. This is the default
>   behavior of all ASP.NET control attributes. When you do not assign an
>   attribute a value, it is not rendered. Unfortunately, in this case, we
>   really want to render an empty string as the alt attribute value.
>
> In order to make sure that HTML rendered for an ASP.NET Image control
>   includes alt="", you must set the GenerateEmptyAlternateText property
>   to true.

Comment: I find it handy to automatically apply the `GenerateEmptyAlternateText="True"` attribute to all images by adding into an App_Themes `.skin` file. Just add a file called `images.skin` into your theme folder and put the contents of the file as `<asp:Image runat="server" GenerateEmptyAlternateText="true" />`

Answer (score -1):

From [MSDN's ImageButton.GenerateEmptyAlternateText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.generateemptyalternatetext.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control generates an alternate-text attribute for an empty string value.
>
> By default, the `ImageButton` control renders the `AlternateText` property using an alt attribute. When the `AlternateText` property is not set, the `ImageButton` control does not include the alt attribute to specify the alternate-text in the control rendering.
>
> The XHTML document type definition requires the alt attribute on image controls. However, accessibility best practices recommend that image controls that do not convey information relevant to the context of the Web page should not specify an alt attribute. You can meet both XHTML and accessibility requirements by setting the `AlternateText` property to `true`.

Comment: That doesn't answer if there's any difference between the two ways of setting the alt text.